# Monodevelop: can't drag widgets

Tags: monodevelop

I am trying to use monodevelop. Just at the beginning I came across an issue:

I was following a tutorial on building a Gtk application (http://monodevelop.com/Stetic_GUI_Designer). I was trying to **drag a button from the Widgets Palette**. Nothing happened. I'd been trying quite a few times without any luck.

After a break I launched monodevelop again and I simply placed a button on the window of the application. After that I removed it, dragged VBox container, and placed menu bar on the window, according to the tutorial instructions. I was pleasantly surprised.

By the second try the same problem occurred - **I was not able to drag any widgets**. Dragging was beginning, there was a “+” sign at the cursor and then - nothing was happening. I cannot figure out what happened by the first time, what the difference was. Have anyone had a similar problem? Monodevelop looks promising, but I can't go on with it. (I tried placing 'Fixed' container on the window, with no result - I could not drag it.)

(monodevelop v. 2.4, ubuntu 11.04, Polish language. 
I did look for an answer to my problem, without much luck, that is why I post this question. The problem is described quite precisely. There is a probability that others encountered the same issue.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to **drag a container on the form** first **before** you can **add widgets** to it. The VBox container is an example of a place where you can put your widgets.

If you want to place widgets where ever you want you can use the **Fixed** container. If you want things to align you can use the **VBox**, **HBox** or **Table containers**. Placing in a widget in one of the fields will automatically adjust the size of this field to fit the widget you have dragged into it.

So basically,

1. Create a form
2. Drag a container on the form
3. Drag a widget inside the container.

These widgets are not to be confused with the custom made widgets (in your **Solution browser**, right click the **folder User Interfaces** and click **Add Widget...**). These are like forms. I use these to create GUI's in advance so I can call these while the program is running.

FYI: if you want to create code for a widget (like a button) you can't just double click it like in Visual Studio. You need to **select it**, the go to the **properties pane**, and **change the tab from Properties to Signals**. You can then double click the "signal" to create the event for which you want to create code. For a button this is usually the **Clicked** event (somewhere at the bottom of the list, you'll need to open the **Button Signals**)

You can always visit the IRC channel of Monodevelop on **irc://irc.gimp.org/monodevelop** (***IRC.Gimp.org #monodevelop***)
I also sit in this channel and can help with smaller problems and I also still use Monodevelop 2.4.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question.

Comment: When I was trying to add components for the first time, I followed the tutorial I mentioned [link](http://monodevelop.com/Stetic_GUI_Designer). I tried to add a button _without any container_ - and  I did - _it filled the whole space_. After that I added a VBox and the window was neatly organized then.

After that one time I wasn't able to add anything to the frame. I thought an upgrade would help, so I upgraded to version 2.6. After that I cannot even see the designer. I click the button, but it doesn't work, as it used to. Nothing happens.

Comment: Is it a _bug_ or is there some _tiny option_ I should have picked? I am looking forward to any suggestions.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a bug then. A screenshot would've been more helpful.